# How can I serve my supervisor?

Tags: ethics

So I am hoping to study a higher scientific degree; research proposal created by myself.

Since - (i) the research interest will be mostly my own, although it will overlap with those of my supervisor (ii) I have experience of teaching and know how exhausting the responsibility can be - I recognise that this is not necessarily a good deal for my prospective supervisor.

And so for reasons - (i) self-interestedly I want to ensure that my supervisor is incentivised to accept my offer & to maintain a meaningful presence (ii) I can empathise with my supervisor & deem that situation unethical - I am brainstorming ways that I can serve my supervisor.

I would especially like to hear from members with direct experience of supervising graduate students although all advice is appreciated.

So far these are my ideas:

*The institution, department & supervisor inherit IP rights to the discovery
*Supervisor may publish the findings
*Offer to teach small group tutorials, lectures or 1:1 voluntarily
*Offer to complete admin duties for supervisor
*Offer to provide outreach for the department

What would really help you as a supervisor that a grad student can do?

Asymptotic Tri

P.S. I don't really want to give up IP rights

Comment: Can you please add some context information in your question: what is your current status and what would be the context of this research: internship, master, PhD? Knowing the country might also help. And why are you looking for such unconventional ways to work with your supervisor? Are they not interested in the topic of your research?

Comment: Hello, the context is PhD level study in the UK. The reason I ask is that I am keen to maintain as much academic independence and freedom as possible, I don't want to work on somebody else's question. However, I realise that I may need to compromise in order to add value. If I were a PI with multiple time commitmemts the last thing I would want is to supervise a grad student whose research interests are specific & not very closely aligned with my own.

Comment: You know many PhD students complain about a lack of supervision, it's probably a more common problem than lack of independence (although it's true that this can happen as well). As Buffy's answer nicely says, it's the supervisor's job to supervise, it's not a favour they do to you. If possible, I'd suggest you try to talk to the supervisor's current or past PhD students to get an idea of their style of supervision.

Answer (score 6):

This may depend a bit on your field (CS), but in mine, none of that would be necessary. All of my students generally worked on their own doctoral proposals with only my advice on things like methodology and such. I made sure they were on track. They published under their own names and only mentioned me in acknowledgements, which was entirely appropriate. I would think that mathematics is just the same, but don't know about things like lab sciences or the humanities.

Your supervisor/advisor is there to serve you. It is part of her/his responsibilities to see that you do a good job, but not to take over any part of your life or intellectual work. Developing a good *personal* relationship with an advisor is very valuable, however.

If you have time for it, you might offer to help him with advising beginning graduate students in finding problems and such, provided that you have a lot of ideas. This would give you some valuable experience for an academic career and also could help build that personal relationship with the advisor. It might also lead to future collaborative work.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I just don't see that there is much benefit for the supervisor in managing a PhD student, if the student's thesis is relatively peripheral to the PI's research interest. I can understand the benefit to the PI of supervising grad students if restricted narrowly to the PI's particular research interest. The benefit, in that case, is free labour; I don't want to labour, I want to think.